# Between-subject comparison contains paired data

Tags: experiment-design, paired-data

*This is a difficult question to search for, so I apologize if it's been addressed elsewhere.*

If I am interested in the effect that weather (sunny/rainy) has on dog running speed, and I have running speeds for a number of dogs, sometimes with a data point for both sunny and rainy for a given dog, sometimes with only sunny or only rainy for a given dog.

> *Sunny*: dog1, **dog3**, dog5, **dog6**, dog8
>
> *Rainy*: dog2, **dog3**, dog4, **dog6**, dog7

**Question: can I just divide up all data into sunny vs. rainy, ignoring the fact that some dogs will appear in both columns, or does that violate an assumption of independence?**

If the answer is no, I could either do a within-subject comparison, but that would require omitting all non-paired data, which cuts my sample size dramatically.  Or I could do between-subjects, which presumably would require (randomly) omitting one weather condition for any dog with weather in both, right?

I'm not doing p-value testing, by the way.  Just effect size (generally Cohen's *d* and graphical comparisons).

Thanks!

(Edited to include simple visualization)